# React-Leaflet same marker in multiple Layers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

How can I add the same marker in multiple Layers in react-leaflet?

**For example:**

I have an app to search for restaurants with react leaflet and every marker is a different restaurant. I want to have a `LayerControl` to filter them by type and rating (1..5 stars).

I can have a `LayerControl.Overlay` to filter by types (e.g. Buffet) but I also want to filter by rating. If I have a restaurant type='buffet' and rating=4 how can I do it for display the marker only when buffet type and 4 star rating are checked.

Here is my [current code](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-layers-control-cftd4?file=/src/App.js) that filters only by type.

I'm using react-leaflet v3.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have a sample dataset we can play with?  My recommendation is not to add the same marker to multiple layers as it will render many markers over the same spot, which is a waste of CPU, and will exaggerate the marker shadow (if you're using one).  It would be better to create a custom layerscontrol that applies filters on a single dataset and renders only the markers that pass the filter parameters.  If you create a sample codesandbox or codepend, we can help you better to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I added an example of my [current code](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-layers-control-cftd4?file=/src/App.js) in the question. I can't have multiple markers for the same restaurant because I only want to display it when both filters (type and rating) are checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are using with creating various layergroups to manage your filters is not the best way to go about it.  I took another approach.

#### Create a state object with your desired filters

In your App, create a state variable that holds potential filters.  We'll set it to initially contain all options:

```js
const restaurantTypes = ["Family Style", "Buffet", "Fast Food", "Cafe"];
const ratings = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function App() {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
    restaurantTypes,
    ratings
  });
  ...
}
```

#### Custom filter component

I opted to create a custom component, which is basically the exact same html markup as a leaflet layercontrol, but without any of the functionality.  You can check out the sandbox at the end of this answer, but all it does is manage the `filters` state variable we just defined.  Here's a brief summary:

```js
const FilterControl = ({ filters, setFilters }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Type</h3>
      {restaurantTypes.map((type) => (
        <label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={filters.restaurantTypes.includes(type)}
            onClick={(e) => {
              if (filters.restaurantTypes.includes(type)) {
                setFilters((prevFilters) => ({
                  ...prevFilters,
                  restaurantTypes: prevFilters.restaurantTypes.filter(
                    (f) => f !== type
                  )
                }));
              } else {
                setFilters((prevFilters) => ({
                  ...prevFilters,
                  restaurantTypes: [...prevFilters.restaurantTypes, type]
                }));
              }
            }}
          />
          <span>{type}/span>
        </label>
      ))}
      <h3>Rating</h3>
      {ratings.map((rating) => (
        // same as above but for ratings
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

So now your `FilterControl` can neatly manage the state of `filters`.

#### Filter the markers according to filter

Now all you have to do is map over your `restaurants` dataset, and only render markers whose `type` and `rating` are in the current `filters`:

```js
function App() {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
    restaurantTypes,
    ratings
  });
  return (
    <MapContainer ... >
      <TileLayer ... />
      <FilterControl filters={filters} setFilters={setFilters} />
      {restaurants.map((restaurant) => {
        if (
          filters.restaurantTypes.includes(restaurant.type) &&
          filters.ratings.includes(restaurant.rating)
        ) {
          return <Marker position={restaurant.coordinates} />
        }
        return null;
      })}
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

### [Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/leaflet-layers-control-forked-tl49y)